# How to test a time series' serial correlation with ties in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I was trying to test serial correlation for a time series measurements (x1,x2,...xn). The problem is that some of them happens in the same date, the time points are (0,0,0,0...0,1,1,1,1,1,....,2,2,2,....). How do I adjust these ties in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a technique known as VAR, for Vector Autoregressive. Package is var. Each of your time points becomes a vector.